# No specs found for project in same workspace as main project

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, specifications

I have been tasked to test an application for a business. Whenever I run the main project with "ng test", it runs normally and finds all of its test suites. However, when I try to run another project in the same workspace, called "corePlugins" with "ng test --project=corePlugins" it does not find any tests in that project, despite there being a test-suite. It also says that no files are matched according to the pattern tag under "files" in the karma.conf.js. I get the following error: Here are my files:

[image]

The test suite gauge-chart.component.spec.ts under core-plugins/src/app/plugins/gauge-chart

```
fdescribe('GaugeChartComponent', () => {
let fixture: ComponentFixture<GaugeChartComponent>;
let component: GaugeChartComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            AppModule,
            PluginsModule
        ],
        providers: [TranslateStore, {provide: PluginDataService, useValue: new MockPluginDataService()}]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GaugeChartComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('renders without errors', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

});
```

test.ts

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    keys(): string[];
    <T>(id: string): T;
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./app/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
   "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
 }
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      // require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    // coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    //   dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './frontend/base/src/app'),
    //   reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
    //   fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    // },
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    },
    preprocessors: {
      '**/src/*.ts': 'coverage'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    files: [
  {
    pattern: 'src/app/plugins/gauge-chart/*.spec.ts',
    watched: false,
    type: 'module'
  }
]
   });
};
```

my angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "fill-angulartemplate": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/cybernetics-analyze-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/3rdpartylicenses.txt"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.prod.config.js"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "jsonserver": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.jsonserver.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "prod-jsonserver": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod-jsonserver.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fill-angulartemplate:build",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
            "port": 4200
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "fill-angulartemplate:build:production",
              "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.prod.config.js"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "fill-angulartemplate:build:development"
            },
            "jsonserver": {
              "browserTarget": "fill-angulartemplate:build:jsonserver"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fill-angulartemplate:build",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/3rdpartylicenses.txt"
            ],
            "sourceMap": true,
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "fill-angulartemplate:serve:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "devServerTarget": "fill-angulartemplate:serve:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
      }
    },
    "corePlugins": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/core-plugins",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/core-plugins/src",
      "prefix": "core-plugins",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/corePlugins",
            "index": "projects/core-plugins/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/core-plugins/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/core-plugins/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/core-plugins/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/core-plugins/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/core-plugins/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/core-plugins/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/core-plugins/webpack.config.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/core-plugins/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/core-plugins/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/core-plugins/webpack.prod.config.js"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "cyberneticsVolume": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/core-plugins/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/core-plugins/src/environments/enviroment.cyberneticsVolume.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "corePlugins:build",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/core-plugins/webpack.config.js",
            "port": 4201
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "corePlugins:build:production",
              "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/core-plugins/webpack.prod.config.js"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "corePlugins:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "corePlugins:build",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/core-plugins/webpack.config.js"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/core-plugins/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/core-plugins/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/core-plugins/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/core-plugins/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/core-plugins/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/core-plugins/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/core-plugins/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/core-plugins/webpack.config.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "projects/core-plugins/**/*.ts",
              "projects/core-plugins/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "projects/core-plugins/e2e/protractor.conf.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "corePlugins:serve:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "devServerTarget": "corePlugins:serve:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
      }
    },
    "@fill/cybernetics-platform-interface": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/**/*.ts",
              "projects/fill/cybernetics-platform-interface/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "fill-angulartemplate",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
const context = require.context('./app/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

to

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

in `test.ts`. That should hopefully do it.

Comment: Still getting the same error. The path in the AfterAll Error is what really confuses me though, since it's actually incorrect. This is the path specified in the 
AfterAll Error: /base/src/app/plugins/gauge-chart/gauge-chart.component.spec.ts
And this is the one I specified in my karma.conf.js "files"-tag: src/app/plugins/gauge-chart/*.spec.ts', which should point to the file at frontend/base/projects/core-plugins/src/app/plugins/gauge-chart/
The latter one, however, finds the spec.ts file since otherwise I would get an error saying that the pattern does not match any file

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.